Convert wav to mulaw in Python
I'm opening a wav file and attempting to convert it into mulaw unsuccessfully. The mulaw is then sent to Twilio to play. The code is as follows:
 with wave.open('audio/test.wav', 'rb') as wav:
    raw_wav= wav.readframes(wav.getnframes())
    raw_ulaw = audioop.lin2ulaw(raw_wav, wav.getsampwidth())

The conversion does happen but the resulting mulaw is just static sound, no speech. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

This is not about Twilio? Also, audioop is deprecated since Python 3.11, which means that getting this to work means it will rely on Python 3.12 or older, since it has been removed in 3.13. https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#audioop

@Grismar What do you suggest I use then?

Although StackOveflow is not the place to ask for recommendations, in this case it's worth noting that lin2ulaw was deprecated and removed, not replaced. So, you do have to look elsewhere. However, using a very common library like numpy, creating your own wave to μ-law conversion function is fairly straightforward and gives you full control over bias, sample rate, etc.  Other questions on StackOverflow provide examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085735/python-u-law-mulaw-wave-decompression-to-raw-wave-signal (although they also still recommend audioop, being older)

Couldn't figure out a reliable way to achieve this so I used ffmpeg to convert .wav files to .mulaw and then just used the latter.

For format conversions, ffmpeg is a solid choice. If you still need to drive it from Python, you can do so through subprocess or more directly with third party libraries that provide Python-bindings for ffmpeg.
